# Using Scheduler Pallet to schedule Contract pallet call

Tags: runtime, extrinsic, chain-extension, call

I'm trying to use the Scheduler pallet to schedule a call to the Contracts pallet as part
of a chain extension implementation.

I've managed to get the following to compile and execute:

```rust
// In `runtime/src/chain_extension.rs`
pub struct MyExtension;

impl<T> ChainExtension<T> for MyExtension
where
    T: pallet_contracts::Config + pallet_scheduler::Config,
{
    fn call<E>(
        func_id: u32,
        env: Environment<'_, '_, E, InitState>,
    ) -> Result<RetVal, DispatchError>
{
...

    let call: <T as pallet_scheduler::Config>::Call =
        frame_system::Call::remark {
            remark: 0u32.encode(),
        }
        .into();

    pallet_scheduler::Pallet::<T>::schedule(
        RawOrigin::Signed(caller).into(),
        at.into(),
        None,
        Default::default(),
        call,
    )?;

...
    }
}
```

Now, when I try and craft a `Call` to the Contracts pallet like so:

```rust
let call = pallet_contracts::Call::remove_code {
    code_hash: Default::default(),
};

let call = crate::Box::new(MaybeHashed::Value(call));
```

It fails with the following error:

```
     Compiling contracts-node-runtime v0.16.0 (/home/hernando/remote-builds/17766829191224950667/runtime)
  error[E0308]: mismatched types
     --> /home/hernando/remote-builds/17766829191224950667/runtime/src/chain_extension.rs:151:21
      |
  146 |                 pallet_scheduler::Pallet::<T>::schedule(
      |                 --------------------------------------- arguments to this function are incorrect
  ...
  151 |                     call,
      |                     ^^^^ expected associated type, found enum `pallet_contracts::Call`
      |
      = note: expected struct `sp_std::prelude::Box<MaybeHashed<<T as pallet_scheduler::Config>::Call, <T as SysConfig>::Hash>>`
                 found struct `sp_std::prelude::Box<MaybeHashed<pallet_contracts::Call<_>, _>>`
      = help: consider constraining the associated type `<T as pallet_scheduler::Config>::Call` to `pallet_contracts::Call<_>` or calling a method that returns `<T as pallet_scheduler::Config>::Call`
      = note: for more information, visit https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html
  note: associated function defined here
     --> /home/hernando/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/c0ee2ad/frame/scheduler/src/lib.rs:425:10
      |
  425 |         pub fn schedule(
      |                ^^^^^^^^

  For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
  error: could not compile `contracts-node-runtime` due to previous error
```

Under the hood the [`Scheduler::schedule`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/6001b59f9f64a133d55fc13a495acc76eb4b532f/frame/scheduler/src/lib.rs#L425) extrinsic is expecting a `<T as pallet_scheduler::Config>::Call`, which from
the `Config` definition is the following:

```rust
type Call: Parameter
    + Dispatchable<Origin = <Self as Config>::Origin, PostInfo = PostDispatchInfo>
    + GetDispatchInfo
    + From<system::Call<Self>>;
```

So the error makes sense. According to the `From` implementation we can only turn system
`Call`s into Scheduler `Call`s, which is why `remark` worked and `remove_code` didn't.

#### Successful Dispatches of non-system Calls

I've tried manually scheduling a Contracts call using the Polkadot JS UI and I'm able to
schedule and execute it successfully. Below is the extrinsic it built:

[image: polkadot-js-apps-contract-call]

There's also the [Referenda pallet which implements some scheduler related traits](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/6001b59f9f64a133d55fc13a495acc76eb4b532f/frame/referenda/src/lib.rs#L131) and that allows it to specify its own `Call` type.

```rust
#[pallet::config]
pub trait Config<I: 'static = ()>: frame_system::Config + Sized {
    /// The Scheduler.
    type Scheduler: ScheduleAnon<
            Self::BlockNumber,
            CallOf<Self, I>,
            PalletsOriginOf<Self>,
            Hash = Self::Hash,
        > + ScheduleNamed<
            Self::BlockNumber,
            CallOf<Self, I>,
            PalletsOriginOf<Self>,
            Hash = Self::Hash,
        >;
}
```

#### Questions

- How is Polkadot JS Apps able to successfully build a Contract `Call` and schedule it?
- How am I able to replicate this in Rust without building a wrapper pallet a la
  `pallet-referenda`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Alright, so I had a chat with Kian about this and he gave me some tips for how to
approach this.

First, we need to distinguish between *Runtime Calls* and *Pallet Calls*.

The Runtime calls are those that are exposed by the runtime. These are generated by the
`construct_runtime!` macro. This type of call indicates which of the pallets included by
the Runtime expose dispatchable functions (a.k.a extrinsics).

Pallet calls are generated from the `#[pallet::call]` FRAME macro and indicate which
dispatchables (extrinsics) are available in a given pallet.

Now, with that background we can break down the error a bit more.

First, let's take a look at a slightly simplified version of the
`pallet_scheduler::Call::schedule()` function signature:

```rust
fn schedule(
    origin: OriginFor<T>,
    ...
    call: <T as pallet_scheduler::Config>::Call,

) -> DispatchResult;
```

This is expecting a *Runtime Call*. We can tell this because it is going through the
associated type `Call` of the Scheduler pallet's `Config` trait, which is wired up in the
Runtime.

Now let's look at the original error again:

```
= note: expected struct `sp_std::prelude::Box<MaybeHashed<<T as pallet_scheduler::Config>::Call, <T as SysConfig>::Hash>>`
                 found struct `sp_std::prelude::Box<MaybeHashed<pallet_contracts::Call<_>, _>>`
```

We are handing the function a `pallet_contracts::Call`, which is a *Pallet Call*. We know
this because we are going directly through the `pallet_contracts` module.

So the question now becomes, how can we provide a *Runtime Call* instead of a *Pallet Call*
to the `schedule()`?

In order to build a Runtime Call for the Contracts pallet we can do the following:

```rust
// Note, `crate` refers to our `runtime/src/lib.rs`
let call = crate::Call::Contracts(pallet_contracts::Call::remove_code {
    code_hash: Default::default(),
});
```

However, this won't work just yet. Remember that we need this to be of the same type as
the Scheduler pallet's associated type `Call`.

Because we're working with generics (as usual when we deal with Substrate) we need to add
the following trait bound in the definition of our chain extension:

```rust
impl<T> ChainExtension<T> for MyExtension
where
    T: pallet_contracts::Config + pallet_scheduler::Config,
    <T as pallet_scheduler::Config>::Call: From<crate::Call>, // <- Added this
{ ... }
```

This specifies a requirement that we need be able to convert *any* Runtime Call into a
Runtime call for the Scheduler pallet.

Luckily for us the `construct_runtime!` macro provides this implementation. So with that
we can now convert our Call into the correct type.

```rust
let call: <T as pallet_scheduler::Config>::Call =
    crate::Call::Contracts(pallet_contracts::Call::remove_code {
        code_hash: Default::default(),
    })
    .into();
```

We can now pass this into the `Scheduler::schedule()` extrinsic and happily go about our
day!